# How would one display different text near the footer, based on the page

Tags: css, printing

So i am trying to create a page that will print data retrieved from a database. These tables can will span across multiple pages. All of the tables, breaking, layout, headers and footers are ready, and the subtotaling functions are ready.

My only problem is the final total location.

What I want is for a document that is say 3 pages long, at the footer level; to have on pages 1 and 2 "cont'd" and on page 3 display the final total.

at the moment, I have a  element that contains the total information, and css that places it in the exact location I want. But it currently appears on every page when printed.

I've looked around at code that on print takes the current page and max page of a print job and can produce the "page x of y", but I want  an "if-else" like logic structure. However I dont know how to do this in css.

Please if I am missing something please tell me.

```
<style>
<!---I know there is a variable structure for CSS but does it require any specific library to be installed?--->

if (currentPage()===maxPage()){//I only want to display the total text on the last page.
     div.total {//the div with the total would be set to none by default
     display:all;
     }
}else{
     div.continue{//the div with the "cont'd" message will be displayed
     display:all;
     }
}


</style>
```

Comment: I don't think you can use if/else in css like that..... what framework are you operating within? or what libraries are you using? Are you printing to pdf? Are you using puppeteer?

Comment: My page is built up in php, not many library aside from jquery. But I am just printing from the browser (right click -> print, Ctrl+P). no buttons, etc. I'm not really using any framework to speak of. Just basic HTML.

Comment: for the most part in the code, I'm just supposing the theoretical logic of the proposed set up. I'm just trying to find some sort of code that will trigger during a print dialogue; that checks if is the last page, and displays the total <div>, else show the continued <div>

Comment: You could use puppeteer to visit that site and print each page. With puppeteer you can add a footer to each page afaik https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.3.0/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions You would need to write a fairly basic nodejs script to do this

Comment: And Puppeteer is an api that works exclusively for Chrome/Chromium based Browsers? or does is support browsers like firefox or safari?

Comment: it uses a version of Chromium. Does that matter? Using the default browser is actually a good thing because it gives consistent results (you know how css can be different in different browsers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"if/else" statements does not exist in CSS. Unless you use a CSS pre-processor which will anyhow produce an outcome as CSS.

If you want to introduce conditional statements you have to move the statements outside of CSS (e.g. javascript, php, etc).

I suggest you start with PHP for your wanted conditional statement, since PHP can communicate with a database and extract data to variables that later can be access from within your HTML code, thus presented in a web browser.

According to your description you will need to store variables that are connected to the browser session. You can do that with PHP interacting with [$_POST] and [$_SESSION].

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what do you mean by CSS preprocessor? I don't really what that is? is it a library? would it trigger during the print dialogue, and would it change the print preview?

Comment: A CSS pre-processor is a software tool that introduces several features such as possiblity to create variables, nesting, partial, imports. The 2 most common ones are Sass and Less. They do support if-statements but note that the outcome of the pre-processing is a plain CSS (without if-statements). Link to Sass: https://sass-lang.com/guide Link to less: http://lesscss.org/

Comment: No it will not change the print preview. It sound you need to breakup your needs into several small pieces and start with one, when you have control over one you go to the next requirement, etc.